# onChange not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

We are working on a project where we are using  boxes, and need one of the select boxes to perform an action when the user selects an item from the list.  This is our first time touching React, let alone building a project, so we are stumped at this point.  What we are using for the onChange code is as follows:

```
    var React = require('react');
    var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;

    var ProgramSelectorComponent = React.createClass({

         propTypes: {
            allPrograms: ReactPropTypes.array.isRequired
          },

        _updateProgram: function(e) {
            this.setState({
                value: "TEST"
            });

        },
        render() {
            var Programs = this.props.allPrograms;
            var options = Programs.map(function (prog) {
                return <option key={ prog.program_id } value={ prog.program_id } >
                    { prog.program_name }
                </option>;

            });


            return (
                <select className="form-control margin-bottom" name="Program" id="programSelect" ref="progRef" onChange={this._updateProgram} >
                    <option value="select">Select</option>
                   {options}
                </select>
            )
        }


    });

    module.exports = ProgramSelectorComponent;
```

I know that rendering does work in the `<select>` tag as I can add something like `data-test-id="test"` and that renders properly, but for some reason, the onChange is not showing in the code, and therefore, not working.

Like I said, we are all new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `onChange` prop will *not* show in the resulting HTML. There is no 1:1 mapping from React to HTML. When you add a `debugger` statement or a `console.log(...)` call in your `_updateProgram` method, does it get called?

Answer (score 0):

In your select tag try: `<select value={this.state.value}>`

This is a good read about controlled vs uncontrolled components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Yeah, we have been all over Facebook's github, as well as multiple other example sites.  We just can't get the onChange to render.  I will pass along the select tag modification.

Comment: Are you sure onChange is not being called? It seems like it's being called and the component's state is changed, which will trigger a re-render. However, your current render function is not using the component's state, so there's no visual change to see when the state changes.